# Cannot use R object in python chunk

Tags: python, r, r-markdown

I am trying to create one RMD file which has python and R chunks, I have a R variable in which I stored my dataset. While trying to access that variable in python chunk with the r object am getting an error

I have installed the required python libraries I need.
I have many R chunks in rmd which is used to wrangle the dataset, thought many r chunks would be ambiguous so tried with inbuilt cars dataset with one r chunk and one python chunk. This is also not working.

```
r chunk 
autos <- cars
```

```
python chunk
import pandas
autos_py = r.autos
```

autos dataset in R chunk should be copied to autos_py in python chunk.

Instead, I am getting the following error

````
  File "/var/folders/r1/0zy0ybkd79n2tbxg428ygnmc0000gn/T/RtmprHvCpd/chunk-code-153f939110d08.txt", line 2, in <module>
    autos_py = r.autos
NameError: name 'r' is not defined```
````

Comment: why not write to a csv file and then reread it, I know it will be time consuming but using data.table::fwrite might hasten it in the R side, the error is thrown because python can't find the `r` object, `.` is a special character in python it seperates an object from it s properties and methods